# Sum different lists from dictionaries PYTHON

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a data structure.  A list of 4 dictionaries each with 4 keys and 3 values in a list.

```
 dict_list = [0]  {key1: [1, 2, 3]
                   key2: [4, 5, 6]
                   key3: [7, 8, 9]
                   key4: [10, 11, 12]

             [1]  {key1: [13.......]
                   key2: [16... etc.
```

I want to sum each sub column [1, 4, 7, 10]....[2,5,8,11] etc. into the form

```
 new_dict_list = [0] {new_key: [(1+4+7+10), (2,5,8,11), (3,6,9,12)]
                 [1] {new_key2: [(13+16....) etc.
```

So I'm  basically cascading each column within each dictionary.

I have a VERY explicit and long way to do it so far (checking the math is correct), is there any way to use list comprehensions for something this long-winded or is it not worth the effort in the end?

Comment: A question, why did `[(1+4+7+10), (2,5,8,11), (3,6,9,12)]` go to `key1` ? How do you determine `key1` there? Please note, `dict` does not have a sense of order.

Comment: where do `key1`, `key2` come from ?

Comment: @AnandSKumar assuming its a a new list of dictionaries, the key is irrelevant.  Key1 in each will be labeled whichever I want.  (edited to be more explicit with that)

Answer (score 4):

Use `zip` to group [1, 4, 7, 10]....[2,5,8,11]:

```
>>> d = dict_list[0]
>>> zip(*d.values())
[(7, 4, 1, 10), (8, 5, 2, 11), (9, 6, 3, 12)]
```

Use `map` to generate the new list:

```
>>> map(sum, zip(*d.values()))
[22, 26, 30]
```

If you are using python3.x, you need `list(map...)` to get the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` and `sum` function :

```
dict_lis=[{next(d.iterkeys()):map(sum,zip(*d.values()))} for d in dict_lis]
```

`dict.iterkeys()` will returns an iterator of dictionary keys which you can get the first key using `next` function.but note that it wouldn't return the first key in the order that you have defined your dictionaries.since dictionary items are not ordered you can use `collections.OrderedDict` to get a ordered dictionary.

**Note** that you shouldn't have same key in your dictionaries!since you can not use same key in the last combined dictionary!

example :

```
dict_lis=[{'key1': [1, 2, 3],'key2': [4, 5, 6],'key3': [7, 8, 9],'key4': [10, 11, 12]},{'key5': [13,14,15],'key6': [16,17,18]}]
print [{next(d.iterkeys()):map(sum,zip(*d.values()))} for d in dict_lis]

[{'key3': [22, 26, 30]}, {'key6': [29, 31, 33]}]
```

Comment: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`

Comment: @BrentWashburne Sorry you need to unpack the values!

Comment: @AnandSKumar I think OP doesn't mean that all the keys are same but `key1` and ... are fake and for demonstrating the example! also i noted that in answer!

Comment: Is there any problem with my answer? I hope down voter care abut comment!

Answer (score 0):

Original version using list comprehensions:

```
# set up the initial data
dict_list = []
dict_list.append({'key1': range(1,4),
                  'key2': range(4,7),
                  'key3': range(7,10),
                  'key4': range(10,13)})
dict_list.append({'key1': range(13,16),
                  'key2': range(16,19),
                  'key3': range(19,22),
                  'key4': range(22,25)})

# generate the new list
new_dict_list = []
for d in dict_list:
    new_dict_list.append({'new_key': [sum(v[0] for v in d.values()),
                                      sum(v[1] for v in d.values()),
                                      sum(v[2] for v in d.values())]  })

print new_dict_list
```

The output looks like this:

```
[{'new_key': [22, 26, 30]}, {'new_key': [70, 74, 78]}]
```

Comment: how about list length larger than 3?

Comment: Your answer is more flexible for variable list lengths.  My answer uses list comprehensions, as requested in the question.